# Creating an ordered flag using date criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data that is in this format:

```
id  start_date  end_date
25  1-Jan-00    24-Jan-00
25  26-Jan-00   5-Feb-00
25  3-Nov-00    6-Mar-01
25  10-Mar-01   4-Jun-02
25  2-Jul-03    6-Aug-03
93  2-May-14    4-May-14
93  8-May-14    6-Aug-14
93  9-Aug-14    1-Feb-15
93  3-Feb-15    14-Mar-15
93  9-Jul-15    1-Dec-15
93  2-Mar-16    7-Mar-16
93  2-Apr-16    1-May-16
```

I want to create a field called 'string_num' that considers a row to be part of a string if the end date of the prior row (ordered by id and start_date) is within 7 days of the start date of the current row.  It would look like this at the end:

```
id  start_date  end_date    string_num
25  1-Jan-00    24-Jan-00   1
25  26-Jan-00   5-Feb-00    1
25  3-Nov-00    6-Mar-01    2
25  10-Mar-01   4-Jun-02    2
25  2-Jul-03    6-Aug-03    3
93  2-May-14    4-May-14    1
93  8-May-14    6-Aug-14    1
93  9-Aug-14    1-Feb-15    1
93  3-Feb-15    14-Mar-15   1
93  9-Jul-15    1-Dec-15    2
93  2-Mar-16    7-Mar-16    3
93  2-Apr-16    1-May-16    4
```

Do I have to use a recursive query for this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using sql developer to connect to an Oracle database

Comment: Hmmm . . . You define logic that is boolean ("if") and call something `string_id`.  Your desired results have an integer and something called `string_num`.  Please clarify the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oops, it should be string_num everywhere.  For each id, i want the first row to have string_num = 1.  For the next row for the same id, I want string_num to be 1 if the start_date of that row is less than 7 days after the end_date of the previous row.  If it is 7 days or more, I want string_num to be 2.  For the next row for that same id, if the start_date is less than 7 days after the previous row's end date, I want string_num to be 2, if it is 7 or more days away, it should say 3.  For each new id, this would start over at 1.  Does that logic make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with analytic functions.  `LAG()` is used to get the previous date.  Then use `SUM()` to do a cumulative sum with some logic:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_end_date + 7 >= start_date then 0 else 1
           end) over (partition by id order by start_date) as string_num
from (select t.*,
             lag(end_date) over (partition by id order by start_date) as prev_end_date
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.